# What does Reinitialize All Subscriptions actually do to the databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I tried to find the answer and came across these MSDN pages but they don't actually explain what happens really:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152771.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189701.aspx

Step by step what does the Reinitialize All Subscriptions option actually do to the database in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a detailed response ideally as like I said, the MSDN pages don't go into details rather one or two sentences that roughly describe the whole process not each step!

Answer (score 4):

Initializing or re-initializing a subscription consists of applying (or re-applying) a snapshot of the publication to that subscription.

This consists of dropping subscribing tables at the subscriber, and recreating them containing the same data as the snapshot. The schema of the relevant tables at the subscriber will therefore match the schema at the publication following a re-initialization.

The Snapshot Agent, which lives on the Distributor, generates the snapshot, although when re-initializing a subscription you can opt to use the existing snapshot. The Distribution Agent then reads the snapshot from the snapshot folder and applies it to its subscription. The Distribution Agent lives on the Distributor for push subscriptions, and on the Subscriber for pull subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

> what does the Reinitialize All Subscriptions option actually do to the database in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Reinitialize Subscriptions marks all the subscriptions to a publications for reinitialization.
It apply a snapshot to each subscriber.

Refer to [Reinitialize Subscription(s) - All Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189701.aspx)

Comment: Can you expand upon this what step by step actually happens during this process e.g. tables get dropped and re-created

Answer (score 1):

When you reinitialize subscriptions, entire snapshot of articles ( schema, data..) Is generated and stored in folder. So next time when distributor agent runs, instead of incremental changes.it takes the snapshot generated and applies it to subscriber.

Comment: Can you expand upon this what step by step actually happens during this process e.g. tables get dropped and re-created

Comment: Well... in different words your whole snapshot will be transferred to every subscriber. This is last thing which your should do ;) If your snapshot has 10GBs and you have few subscribers and you are using internet for replication it will take long time. As option for you can start replication from backup for every subscriber. With this approach you can control rein it process step by step.